# Customize Cancel button of Twitter framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

[image]I am using twitter framework .There is cancel and send buttons on the `UIView` which is present when we call the `TWTweetComposeViewController` class. I want  to change the color of Cancel Button as of send button but currently it shows gray color.I tried to reach the subviews and found that Cancel button is of type `UIButtonLabel` which is private class . However it is subclass of `UILabel` and tried to change the color by using condition that it's superclass is `UILabel` and text is Cancel.
When I try to `NSLog` the subviews it sometimes nslogs it but sometimes does not print the superview of Cancel button (which is a `UIButton`).  I have print the details of that button :

```
 <UIButton: 0x859fe10; frame = (265 7; 52 30); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x859fea0>>.....(
"<UIImageView: 0x85b8910; frame = (0 0; 52 30); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x85b7c30>>",
"<UIButtonLabel: 0x859ffb0; frame = (6 7; 40 15); text = 'Cancel'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x85a0020>>")
```

Is it possible to change the color of the button ? Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider [DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController), an open-source clone of the official TWTweetComposeView controller, which is also compatible with iOS 4.

It looks exactly like the official controller out of the box, but being open-source you can easily customize it.

Comment: thanx gabro for your response i wll check it

Comment: glad to help. If the answer helped you, you may consider accepting it ;)